# Android Wear: Custom notification layout cleared before transition

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I'm using a custom notification layout on Android Wear by setting

`WearableExtender.setDisplayIntent()`

When the user taps this layout, I break out into a full screen activity on the Wearable.  The custom activity embedded in the notification stops and clears before the new fullscreen activity is shown with a slide in transition.  This leaves an ugly black box inside the notification container that used to be filled with the embedded activity.  The same thing happens when swiping to close the full screen activity - the crossfade transition shows the empty notification container during the transition, and only restarts its embedded activity afterwards.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?  I can start the fullscreen activity with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` flag, but that doesn't solve the issue when swiping to dismiss it, and ideally I'd like to keep the transitions.

I tried setting the `theme` for the fullscreen activity to translucent, hoping it would only pause the previous activity instead of stopping it, but it was still stopped and cleared.

Comment: This is happening to me as well, I don't know the solution yet, but would like to hear one.

Comment: @Wadlax I've not found a way to fix it yet, but the effect is considerably mitigated by using a fade in transition instead of the default slide in. Try `overridePendingTransition( android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out );` right before your `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` of the full screen activity.

Comment: Just for custom notifications - Can you give details about your THEME? If it is just about formatting text and changing small icon. There are multiple ways for that. Just take a look at **Spannable** in Android.

Comment: @Vintesh I'm just using the standard `DeviceDefault.Light` theme, nothing special. The use of an embedded activity in my case has no relation to text formatting and can not be replaced with a `Spannablle`. @Mario No news, this is still an issue on 4.4W.2